# I want to show product items into shopping cart when i click add to card button using laravel 6.0?

Tags: html, laravel

I am trying to show product items into shopping cart when i click add to card button how to fix it error?  Call to undefined function Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\array_get()

https://flareapp.io/share/B5ZeYg7o#F46

**Controller**

```
    public function cart()
    {
    return view('frontend/cart');
    }
     public function addCart(Request $request)
    {
    $product = Product::findOrFail($request->id);

    $cartItem = Cart::add([
    'id' => $product->id,
    'product_name' => $product->name,
    'product_brand'=>$product->product_brand,
     'qty' => $request->qty,
     'product_price' => $product->product_price,
       ]);
     Cart::associate($cartItem->rowId, 'App\Product');
      return redirect()->route('cart.index');
       }
       }
```

**model product**

```
             class product extends Model
              {
         protected $fillable =[ 'id', 'product_name', 'product_price', 
         'product_image', 
          'product_brand'];
         }
```

**html view**

```
                 <tbody class="cart-table__body">
                 @foreach (Cart::content() as $item)
                 <tr class="cart-table__row">
                <td class="cart-table__column cart-table__column--image">
                  <a href=""><img src="{{ asset($item->model->image) }}" alt="product">
                   </a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="cart-table__column cart-table__column--product">
                    <a href="" class="cart-table__product-name">{{$item->model->product_name}}</a>    
                   </td>
                   <td class="cart-table__column cart-table__column--price" data-title="Price"> 
                   {{$item->model->product_price}}</td>
                   <td class="cart-table__column cart-table__column--quantity" data- 
                    title="Quantity">
                    <div class="input-number">
                    <input class="form-control input-number__input" type="number" min="1" value=" 
                    {{$item->qty}}">
                     <div class="input-number__add"></div>
                     <div class="input-number__sub"></div>
                     </div>
                     </td>
                    <td class="cart-table__column cart-table__column--total" data-title="Total"> 
                     </td>

                    <td class="cart-table__column cart-table__column--remove">
                     <a href="" class="btn btn-light btn-sm btn-svg-icon">
                     <svg width="12px" height="12px">
                     <use xlink:href="{{url('public/assets/images/sprite.svg#cross-12')}}"></use>
                      </svg>
                      </a>
                      </td>
                      </tr>
                       @endforeach
                       </tbody>
```

**form html view**

```
        <form action="{{route('cart.action')}}" method="post" 
         class="product__options">
         {{ csrf_field() }}
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$single_products->id}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value=" 
        {{$single_products->product_name}}">
         <input type="hidden" name="product_image" value=" 
         {{$single_products- 
          >product_image}}">
          <input type="hidden" name="product_brand" value=" 
          {{$single_products->product_brand}}">
          <input type="hidden" name="product_price" value=" 
         {{$single_products->product_price}}">
         <div class="form-group product__option">
         <label class="product__option-label" for="product- 
          quantity">Quantity</label>
          <div class="product__actions">
           <div class="product__actions-item">
            <div class="input-number product__quantity">
            <input id="product-quantity" name="qty" class="input- 
             number__input form-control 
               form-control-lg" type="number" min="1" value="1">
                <div class="input-number__add"></div>
                <div class="input-number__sub"></div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product__actions-item product__actions-item-- 
                addtocart">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Add to 
                 cart</button>
                </div>
                <div class="product__actions-item product__actions-item-- 
                wishlist">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-svg- 
                 icon btn-lg" data- 
                toggle="tooltip" title="Wishlist">
                <svg width="16px" height="16px">
                <use xlink:href=" 
                  {{url('public/assets/images/sprite.svg#wishlist- 
                  16')}}"></use>
                </svg>
                </button>
                </div>
                <div class="product__actions-item product__actions-item-- 
                 compare">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-svg- 
                 icon btn-lg" data- 
                 toggle="tooltip" title="Compare">
                <svg width="16px" height="16px">
                <use xlink:href=" 
                 {{url('public/assets/images/sprite.svg#compare-16')}}"> 
                  </use>
                </svg>
                </button>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </form>


 Route::get('/cart','CartController@cart')->name('cart.index');
```

Route::post('cart/action','CartController@addcart')-

> name('cart.action');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel introduced breaking changes around 5.8/6.0 wherein they removed a lot of the helper functions in favor of using the facades.

The problem is that this function:

```
arr_get()
```

which is the cause of the error, is unfortunately no longer part of the standard Laravel build.  If it was in your own class, you could change this out to use the facade:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
```

and then in your method:

```
Arr::get();
```

Instead of changing the vendor code, you could check to see if you have the latest version of the shopping cart package, which would be compatable with Laravel's later versions... or you can add [the helper package from Laravel](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/helpers) that will bring back those helpers into your base Laravel distro.